# Agrupacion de datos

Tags: sql

buenas noches, necesito hacer una query y no doy con la que necesito. tengo una tabla con actividades, que duran, o no, mas de un dia, y en cada actividad 1 o hasta 3 empleados que realizan la actividad, seria algo asi

```
Actividad - fechaInicio - FechaFin - Empleado1 - Empleado2 - Empleado3
```

Ahora, tengo que contar cuantos dias dura cada actividad, los agrupo y saco cuantos dias trabajo cada empleado en el mes, pero solo me lo hace por empleado1, no me suma el empleado2 ni el 3, les pego la query, para que sea mas grafico.

```
SELECT a.FechaInicio
,e.DiaAcuerdo
,SUM(datediff(day, a.FechaInicio, a.FechaFin)+1) as DiasTrabajados
,(e.DiaAcuerdo - sum (datediff (day, a.FechaInicio, a.FechaFin)+1)) as DiasRestantes
,(E.Nombre +' ' + E.Apellido) as Nombre
from Actividades as A
inner join Empleados E on
    a.ID_Emp = E.ID_Emp 
inner join Empleados E2 on
    a.ID_Emp1 = E2.ID_Emp
inner join Empleados E3 on
    a.ID_Emp1 = E3.ID_Emp
where DATEPART(month, A.FechaInicio) = DATEPART(month, getdate()) 
group by a.FechaInicio, a.FechaFin, a.ID_Emp,e.Nombre,e.Apellido,e.DiaAcuerdo
```

Esta query me trae

```
    2018-06-03  20  18  2   Paula Alvarez
```

Podrian darme una mano? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Para poder ayudarte con esto, necesitamos saber datos de entrada, cual es la salida esperada de esos datos, y que te trae realmente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El principal problema en tu caso es pasar una estructura horizontal como `Actividades` que tiene hasta tres columnas por empleado, a una vertical, dónde solo tengas una sola columna por empleado y entonces poder de esa forma hacer un `SUM()` sobre todo. De más está decir que lo ideal sería manejar un registro por Actividad/Empleado, pero si ya no puedes modificar esto, una solución posible sería hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT  E.ID_Emp,
    E.Nombre +' ' + E.Apellido as Nombre,
    e.DiaAcuerdo,
    SUM(A.DiasTrabajados)                   AS 'DiasTrabajados',
    e.DiaAcuerdo - SUM(A.DiasTrabajados)    AS 'DiasRestantes'
    FROM (  SELECT  ID_Emp                  AS 'ID_Emp',
            SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, FechaInicio, FechaFin)+1)     AS 'DiasTrabajados',
            FROM Actividades
            WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, FechaInicio) = DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) 
            GROUP BY ID_Emp

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  ID_Emp1                     AS 'ID_Emp',
            SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, FechaInicio, FechaFin)+1)     AS 'DiasTrabajados',
            FROM Actividades
            WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, FechaInicio) = DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) 
            GROUP BY ID_Emp1

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  ID_Emp2                     AS 'ID_Emp',
            SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, FechaInicio, FechaFin)+1)     AS 'DiasTrabajados',
            FROM Actividades
            WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, FechaInicio) = DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) 
            GROUP BY ID_Emp2
    ) A
    INNER JOIN Empleados E 
        ON A.ID_Emp = E.ID_Emp 
    GROUP BY E.ID_Emp,
        E.Nombre,
        E.Apellido,
        E.DiaAcuerdo
```

- Básicamente tenemos una consulta principal que es casi tu misma consulta repetida 3 veces por cada empleado.
- Nota, que quite del `GROUP BY` las fechas, es un contrasentido buscar la suma de los días trabajados por empleado, y las fechas en cada actividad.
- Con las tres consultas obtenemos un total por cada empleado en cada una de las tres columnas por actividad.
- Lo único que no resta hacer es volver a sumar y ahora sí obtener un único total por Empleado.

Comment: Patricio, finalmente llegue a la misma solucion que vos me das, se que no es lo mas performante pero funciona por ahora hasta que pueda modificar la DB. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Según tu pregunta solo quieres saber los días que dura cada actividad, para ello no es necesario que sepas que cantidad de días que trabajo cada uno, así que yo lo haría de la siguiente manera.

```
--Presumo que actividad es el (idActividad)
SELECT actividad, DATEDIFF(DD,diaInicio,diaFin) FROM Actividades
GROUP BY actividad
```

Comment: Buen dia! Si, pero luego tengo que sumar todos los dias trabajados por cada empleado en el mes, por lo que tengo que contabilizar cada actividad y cuantos empleados trabajaron en cada actividad, para saber cuantos dias trabajo cada uno, indistintamente si estan en ID_Emp1, 2 o 3

Comment: Yo hago algo asi       **  select A.ID_Emp
  ,A.ID_Emp1
  ,A.ID_Emp2
  ,sum(DATEDIFF(day, A.FechaInicio, A.FechaFin))+1 as 
    DiasTrab
  from Actividades as A
 where Datepart(month, A.FechaInicio) = 
    DATEPART(month,getdate())
 group by A.ID_Emp, 
    A.FechaInicio,A.FechaFin,A.ID_Emp1,A.ID_Emp2'**

Comment: Eso me da como resultado un resultset con los dias que trabajo cada empleado en cada actividad, no los puedo sumar y, ademas, si un empleado me aparece en ID_Emp2 o en ID_Emp1 no los puedo agrupar ni sumar